# Nodejs Https Certification

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

Recently I bought a ssl certification

Now I have 5 files:

1) COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

2) COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt

3) AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt

4) www_photoshooter_gr.crt

5) key.key (which is the private key)

I know that I have to create an https nodejs server like this sample

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var opts = {key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')};

https.createServer(opts, function (req, res) {
    res.end('secured!');
}).listen(4443);
```

**but I don't have .pem files!!! How can I create them?**

Comment: Concatenate your certificates into 1. Just add the key as it is: https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/6487319

Comment: .key and .crt are both pem formatted files. It doesn't matter that they have a different extension. They'll still work: http://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file

Comment: You are all right... I create the concatenate file and almost work..

http://photoshooter.gr:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js it works... (http)
but when if I change the script to work with https... It returns "Cannot GET /socket.io/socket.io.js"!! (
https://photoshooter.gr:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js)

Comment: Everything is fine... My mistake!!! Thank youuuuu

Answer (score 1):

I do it like so :

```
var server = https.createServer({ 
        key: fs.readFileSync('secret/server.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('secret/server.crt'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('secret/ca.crt'),
        requestCert: true, rejectUnauthorized: false 
    }, app);
```

Where app is an Express app.

You can replace **server.key** with **key.key**, **server.crt** with **www_photoshooter_gr.crt** and **ca.crt** with  **COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt**